# Output/Write a String in a inline anonymous element - JQuery

Tags: jquery, printf

I'm with a really simple problem but for some reason I can't find the solution.
The page is being fetched using ajax.

The problem is, I have a JavaScript string and I want to write to a given element (without having to do a jquery select), for instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myString = "Test";</script>
<h1><script type="text/javascript">myString</script></h1>
```

I'm trying to use `document.write(myString)` but it's overwritting the entire page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write()` can be used inline in the page while the original page is loading.  If you use it after the page has already loaded (which is what happens when there's an ajax call running), it will clear the entire page and then write a new page.  So, you can't use it then to modify existing content.

The ONLY way to modify HTML after the page is loaded is to use javascript to manipulate the DOM.  That will nearly always involve using selectors to find the right objects in the page to modify.  So ... I don't know why you say you want to do this with jQuery select as that is the right way to do it.

I'd suggest something like this:

HTML:

```
<h1 id="viewTitle"></h1>
<h2 id="viewOutput"></h2>
```

Javascript (run from the ajax call success handler after content put into the page):

```
jQuery("#viewTitle").html(jQuery.i18n.prop('view_title'));
jQuery("#viewOutput").html(jQuery.i18n.prop('view_output'));
```

Comment: Problem is that I didn't want to have to use selectors :/

Comment: Why not use selectors?  This is exactly what they're for!

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine to use `document.write` to output content while the page is loading:

```
<div id="asdf" title="Headline 1" name="Headline 2"></div>

<h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write($('#asdf').attr('title'));</script>
</h1>

<h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write($('#asdf').attr('name'));</script>
</h2>
```

(Note: The code only uses selectors to get values to write.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/4Cxb3/

If the entire page is replaced, it means that you are trying to write the content when the page has completed loading. If the document is not open for writing any more, it will open a new document to write to.